# Drupal 7 Default Node "View" Template

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am working on Drupal 7.23. I would like to know if there is a way to modify the node template when viewed. I am NOT trying to change it on the main page or when searched by tags or any other means. I am trying to change the view or display when a node is selected.

Usually there are 2 tabs for any node or content_type i.e "view" and "edit". I need to change the template for "view". Thank you.

Zain

Answer (score 0):

By default, Drupal provides two display modes for nodes: default and teaser. Both these view modes are generally rendered using node.tpl.php. Either modify this file to fit your needs or use hook_theme_suggestions() to create separate tpl files for different views.